# How to show a moving object on google maps in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to show a route with a moving marker/object on google maps in ruby on rails ? What is the efficient way of doing it ?

Comment: You would have to get the coordinates of the objects using geocoded or using some js or by other options for after every few seconds and then send the coordinates to the rails app and display them using geocoder.

Comment: what should be used for getting coordinates and then updating on map ? 
1 option is to have set time out of some seconds and send an ajax request. I guess it will be very heavy process.
What can be the other alternative ?

Comment: I assume you are using a mobile devise while on the move. You could use your mobile's GPS and network to get the current location coordinates. Also HTML5 now gives you coordinates so you would have to write refresh logic in your view and update the map from the controller. I am not sure how ajax calls would help in getting the coordinates.

Comment: I doubt rails is the framework to go with this particular usecase. There are ways to make ruby go multithreaded and event-driven but it's just not what it was made for.
You tagged this question with node.js for a good reason, because a javascript driven controller could handle your needs a lot better than a ruby driven controller.
Consider changing your framework for this thing. :)

Comment: A combination of jt-rails-address, rails 5 actioncable and google maps maybe. Challenging, but should work given the correct input. Did you manage to get this to work already?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Action Cable to broadcast the coordinates to the UI, save them in some data attributes and poll them from your map script.

You can follow the steps below:

- Create a new channel. Lets call it 'locations':

  `rails g channel locations`
- Broadcast the latest coordinates as you receive them:

  `ActionCable.server.broadcast 'locations_channel', { latitude: 'NEW_LATITUDE', longitude: 'NEW_LONGITUDE' }`
- Once you receive the latest coordinates on the UI, you can set them as data attributes for your map `div` like this:
  `$('#map').data(data);`
  You can find the code snippet for this part in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/muaad/a4cccd20a82cc506332f695b67305c12)
- Poll the map `div`'s data attributes at a regular interval and update the marker's position with:
  `marker.setPosition(latlng)`

I have written [a step by step guide on Medium on how to do this](https://medium.com/@muaad/real-time-google-maps-integration-for-ruby-on-rails-with-action-cable-9dd1042ee163). You can take a look for more.